# Rails order by foreign key (including nil)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to sort column `Foo` that has one `Bar`. Currently, I'm using a join so that in the `foos#index` action is ordered by `bars.name`*:

```
@foos = Foo.joins(:bar).order("bars.name")
```

The problem is, not all `foos` have a `bar`, and it seems as though this join ignores any `Foo` with no `Bar`. I don't want these records ignored. Is there a way to do this?

*For the record, I'm using `will_paginate`, so the `index` action actually includes:

```
@foos = Foo.joins(:bar).paginate :page => params[:page], :order => "bars.name"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SQL `LEFT JOIN` in your `joins` statement. This will fetch all Foos (with Foos that have Bars)
To use 'Rails way' you can wrap it into the scope:

```
scope :some_scope_name, joins("LEFT JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id")
```

Comment: Is there an ActiveRecord way to do this, or will I have to write straight SQL?

Comment: @clem you can try this `Foo.find(:all, :limit => 10,
            :joins => "LEFT JOIN foos ON foo.id = bar.id" ,
            )` That should be the syntax to get your left join instead of inner join. You can use the syntax with `.join` as well, no reason to use `.find`.

Comment: By default joins statement uses INNER JOIN. For other JOINS you should exactly specify kind of join - LEFT or RIGHT. Please let me know if it helped you

Comment: write this: LEFT JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id. Ambiguos column name exception raises when there is multiple columns with the same name in different tables which you want to join

Comment: you are welcome, check my post also I have updated it, it would be helpful too